# Problema para subir imagen a mySQL usando php

Tags: php, html, mysql, imagen

antes que nada quisiera disculparme si esto es una pregunta muy basica u offtopic. Pero es que siento que la solucion a este problema es algo simple pero no lo he podido encontrar.

Estoy haciendo una pagina de registro de estudiantes, y lo estoy haciendo por partes.

Actualmente estoy intentando hacer que se pueda subir una imagen de perfil cuando se añade un estudiante a la base de datos, el codigo actual es:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
      Subir alumno e imagen
    </h1>

  </div>

  <li>

    <h3>
      La forma siguiente es para subir datos de un alumno junto con una imagen.
      Asegurese que sea 300x300 pixeles
    </h3>
    <ul>

     <form action="../api/imagen.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form">
      ID Alumno: <input type="text" name="id_est"><br>
      Nombre Alumno: <input type="text" name="nombre_est"><br>
      Imagen alumno:<input type="file" name="imagen">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form> 
    </ul>
    <body>

        <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $id_est = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id_est');
    $nombre_est = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nombre_est');
    $imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));
    if(!empty($id_est)){
        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbusername = "root";
        $dbpassword = "";
        $dbname = "test";

        //Aqui se crea la conexion

        $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost ,$dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

        if(mysqli_connect_error()){
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        else{
            if(!empty($nombre_est)){
                // Attempt insert query execution

                $sql = "INSERT INTO est VALUES ('$id_est', '$nombre_est', '$imagen')";

                if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
                    echo "Estudiante ingresado";
                } else{
                    echo "ERROR ". mysqli_error($conn);
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "ERROR DE IMAGEN";
            }
        }

        $conn->close();
    }
    else{
        echo "Por favor, ponga un id";
        die;
    }
?>

    </body>
  </li>
</html>
```

Use el comando addslashes debido a un tutorial que estoy siguiendo (y no me marco como comando $_FILES). El problema no "crashea" la pagina, pero si me muestra el codigo de error, este siendo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi linea 31 es:

```
    $imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));
```

¿Ahi un problema en el html?, ¿Deberia dar un valor cualquiera a imagen antes de hacer cualquier cosa?

Debo decir tambien, estoy usando Xampp como servidor (con localhost) y la base de datos de mysql que incluye.

Tambien, este es mi segundo intento de codigo para lograr subir una imagen, mi codigo anterior era exactamente igual, excepto por la linea 31 que tenia:

```
$imagen = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imagen');
```

Este codigo no tiraba error, pero al hacer un select desde otra instancia de localhost, me retornaba el nombre del archivo. (En mySQL el tipo de archivo es largeblob)

Repito, mil disculpas si esta pregunta no pertenece a aqui, y si asi es porvafor avisad y la borro de inmediato.

Comment: Si aceptas un consejo, no almacenes imágenes en la base de datos. Con PHP guarda la imagen en una carpeta y almacena en la base de datos un varchar con la ruta a dicha imagen.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, tratare de hacerlo asi.

Pero el tema es que justo me lo pidio un profesor (proyecto de titulo), tratare de usar ambas formas

Comment: Si guardas en la base de datos el binario de la imagen, ¿Como la muestras, con data: image/*;base64? Y como le comenté a @Jesús : Siempre es bueno resaltar la importancia de parametrizar las consultas a las bases de datos. Además, si se desea mostrar la imagen sin URL en src mediante base64, addslashes() da problemas al intentar mostrarla. Quizás sea necesario invertir el proceso antes de pasar a base64.

Answer (score 1):

La clave primaria del ID del Alumno es AUTO INCREMENT?, por que al parecer **el error sugiere que estas intentando insertar un ID con valor 6 que ya se encuentra en la tabla**, verifica primero eso, y si quieres guardar una imagen, te sugiero crees una carpeta llamada imágenes, tu campo de imagen o foto en tu tabla ponlo varchar(30), cuando la almacenes puedes emplear el siguiente código:
    //Obtenemos el nombre de la foto.

```
function get_ext($archivo){
        $tmp = explode(".", $archivo);
        return end($tmp);
}

//Esto puedes meterlo a una función para re usarla.
$nombre_img = $_FILES['foto']['name']; // foto es tu input de tipo file.
        if(!empty($nombre_img)){
            $ext = get_ext($_FILES['foto']['name']);
            $miFoto = 'nombre_foto'.$ext;
            if($_FILES['foto']['size'] <= 3*1048576){ //Equivalente a un MB.
                if (($_FILES["foto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
                    || ($_FILES["foto"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
                    || ($_FILES["foto"]["type"] == "image/png")){
                    $dir = PATH_ASSETS . 'imagenes/';  // Ruta de tus imagenes
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $dir.'$miFoto);
                }else{
                    $errors[] = "Formato de foto invalida.";
                }
            }else{
                $errors[] = "Tamano de la foto demasiado grande.";
            }
        }else{
            $errors[] = "Foto por defecto"; //Aqui podrias especificar una foto.
        }
```

// En caso de errores, los devolvemos.

```
if(!empty($errors)){
        $final = '<br>';
        foreach ($errors as $e)
            $finale .= '<p>' . $e . '</p>';
        echo $finale;
}
```

Espero te funcione, si no cualquier duda déjala por aquí.

Answer (score 1):

Primero te recomiendo que si vas a almacenar imágenes, (que no es lo mejor) utilices en tu base de datos el tipo de variable BLOB.

Te dejo este codigo que solo es para subir la foto y a mi me funciona

```
<?php

include ("conexion.php");

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$Imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['Imagen']['tmp_name']));

$query = "INSERT INTO tabla_imagen(nombre,Imagen) VALUES('$nombre', '$Imagen')";
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);

if($resultado){
    header("(A donde te va a llevar despues de guardar la foto)");

}
else{
    echo "No se inserto";
}

?>
```

Tienes que crear un archivo de tu conexion y luego enlazarlo a este codigo, si tienes otra duda me dices

Comment: Otra cosa es que te recomiendo que en vez de que tu establezcas una medida de pixeles en las imagenes, que mejor lo especifiques pero si alguien no la sube de ese temaño que tu la adaptes, es muy sencillo, solo estableces el height y width de la etiqueta <img>  :)

Comment: Siempre es bueno resaltar la importancia de parametrizar las consultas a las bases de datos. Además, si se desea mostrar la imagen sin URL en src mediante base64, addslashes() da problemas al intentar mostrarla. Quizás sea necesario invertir el proceso antes de pasar a base64.